# Spinners not initializing to correct arrays

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I've got an app with three spinners, they have unique IDs and I'm trying to use the following code to initialize them:

```
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinDouble);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.double_nums, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinReroll);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.reroll_nums, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);

    Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinTarget);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter3 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.target_nums, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner3.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinTarget.setSelection(3);
```

They initialize and are filled with values, sure enough, but looking at the arrays in strings.xml:

```
<string-array name="reroll_nums">
    <item>10</item>
    <item>9</item>
    <item>8</item>
    <item>7</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item >4</item>
    <item >3</item>
    <item >2</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="double_nums">
    <item>10</item>
    <item>9</item>
    <item>8</item>
    <item>7</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item >4</item>
    <item >3</item>
    <item >2</item>
    <item >1</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="target_nums">
    <item>10</item>
    <item>9</item>
    <item>8</item>
    <item>7</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item >4</item>
    <item >3</item>
    <item >2</item>
    <item >1</item>
</string-array>
```

Spinner #2 (spinReroll) should have values from 2-10 while the others should have values 1-10, but when I run this app in my virtual device, all three spinners have 1-10 values, which is bad since selecting 1in in spinReroll creates an infinite loop :P

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2); 
                            ^^^
 spinner3.setAdapter(adapter3);
                            ^^^
```

you set first `adapter` instead of `adapter2` and also spinner3.

Comment: also spinner3.setAdapter(adapter3);